# Flutter build apk failing with BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 62

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

My app used to run perfectly fine a few days ago, I did NOT do any updates and today it is not building.

My system -

HP 15s eq2144au
AMD Ryzen 3 5300U

Flutter doctor -

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 2.13.0-0.0.pre.604, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.613], locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.11)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[!] Android Studio
    X android-studio-dir = /usr/local/android-studio
    X Android Studio not found at /usr/local/android-studio
[√] VS Code (version 1.66.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

The error -

```
PS C:\Users\my_user_name\Documents\my_project_folder> flutter build apk

 Building with sound null safety

Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\my_user_name\Documents\my_project_folder\android\build.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\my_user_name\Documents\my_project_folder\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\my_user_name\.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1l5ett1r4oxtcv991nxlv5dyv).
      > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 62

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         1,804ms
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

What I have tried -

I have tried setting the `compileSdkVersion` in the `build.gradle` file located in `project_folder\android\app` to `28` and then `30` but that changes nothing.

My `build.gradle` file located in `project_file\android\` -

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My `build.gradle` file located in `project_folder/android/app` -

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }
   
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId myappid
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.4')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

When I run it on Chrome, it works fine, the problem is only with Android.

Thanks!